# Characterization of hitting time's law. (Proof check)

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, proof-verification, martingales, stopping-times

Under the same assumptions of [this early question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/514527/reality-check-on-martingal-proof), consider also a the random time $T_a := \inf\{ t > 0: B_t \geq a\}$ which is a stopping time.
Since $M^\lambda$ is a continuous martingale, Doob's optional sampling theorem implies that

$$ \mathbb E \left\{ \exp(\lambda \ B_{T_a\ \wedge\  n} -\frac{\lambda^2}{2}({T_a\ \wedge\  n})) \ |\ \mathcal F_s  \right\}=\mathbb E \{M^\lambda _{T_a\ \wedge\  n}\ |\ \mathcal F_s  \}= M^\lambda _0=1$$

Then, we can show that conditionally to $\{ T_a < + \infty \}$

$$ \exp(\lambda \ B_{T_a\ \wedge\  n} -\frac{\lambda^2}{2}({T_a\ \wedge\  n})) \underset{n\rightarrow 0}{\overset{\mathbb P -\text{ae}}\longrightarrow} e^{\lambda a}\exp(-\frac{\lambda^2}{2}{T_a}) $$

and conditionally to $\{ T_a = + \infty \}$

$$ \exp(\lambda \ B_{T_a\ \wedge\  n} -\frac{\lambda^2}{2}({T_a\ \wedge\  n})) \underset{n\rightarrow 0}{\overset{\mathbb P -\text{ae}}\longrightarrow} 0 $$

Now, my claim is that this second event has null measure. In other words,

$$\mathbb P \{T_a < + \infty \}=1 .$$ 
Indeed, since $0 \leq \exp(\lambda \ B_{T_a\ \wedge\  n} -\frac{\lambda^2}{2}({T_a\ \wedge\  n}))\leq e^{\lambda a}$, the dominated convergence theorem implies

$$e^{\lambda a}\mathbb E \left\{\exp(-\frac{\lambda^2}{2}{T_a})\mathbf 1_{\{ T_a < + \infty\}}\ |\ \mathcal F_s  \right\}= \mathbb E \left\{\lim_{n \rightarrow +\infty}\exp(\lambda \ B_{T_a\ \wedge\  n} -\frac{\lambda^2}{2}({T_a\ \wedge\  n})) \mathbf 1_{\{ T_a < + \infty\}} \ |\ \mathcal F_s  \right\}=1 $$

At this point we can construct a monotonic decreasing sequence $(\lambda_n)$ converging to zero, witch give us by monotone convergence theorem that 
$$\mathbb P \{T_a < + \infty \}=1 .$$

Therefore, we are able to conclude that
$$\mathbb E \left\{\exp(-\frac{\lambda^2}{2}{T_a})\ |\ \mathcal F_s  \right\}= e^{-\lambda a}$$

Could any fellow check out my arguments, specially the dominated convergence thm., please?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you should delete $\mathcal{F}_s$ in your statement.